# How do we assert the JSON response field type (if it's String or int)?

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

How do we assert the JSON response field type?

```json
{
  "Data" : [
     "Id" : 1,
     "Name" : "ABC"
  ]
}
```

Is there any way to validate that `ID` should contain an `int` and `Name` should be a `String`? I don't want to validate the values.

Comment: Do you want to make sure the value gets set as a specific type or want to know what type it is while reading it? In Json itself there are no fixed datatypes if this answers your question.

Comment: Dear @Bob, Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, note that the provided JSON document is not valid. Should `Data` be an array of objects or an object? Could you please correct the JSON document?

Comment: Try looking at [Validate JSON Schema in Rest Assured](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/validate-json-schema-in-rest-assured).

Comment: @Japhei I want to validate the type. For example, For Name the value should be in String only.

//This Should Fail as we got Name is not in String. 
{
  "Data" : [
     "Id" : 1,
     "Name" :ABC
  ]
}


//Valid one, It should pass
{
  "Data" : [
     "Id" : 1,
     "Name" : "ABC"
  ]
}

Comment: @Bob again, when so you want to validate it? While reading the file or while writing it? There is no way to just  tell Json to only accept specific datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

## Overview

You are asking how to check the JSON document structure.
JSON document validation against a JSON schema (JSON schema validation) is a way to perform such check.

## Introduction

Let's consider the following versions as the current versions:

- REST Assured: `5.1.1`.
- JUnit: `5.8.2`.

## Solution

REST Assured supports JSON schema validation.

- [Usage: Examples: JSON Schema validation · rest-assured/rest-assured Wiki](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#json-schema-validation).
- [JsonSchemaValidator (json-schema-validator 5.1.1 API)](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/json-schema-validator/5.1.1/io/restassured/module/jsv/JsonSchemaValidator.html).

### Draft example unit test

The unit test class contain two tests: successful and failing.

The failing test fails with the following message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Response body doesn't match expectation.
Expected: The content to match the given JSON schema.
error: instance type (object) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: ["string"])
    level: "error"
    schema: {"loadingURI":"file:/<the-project-path>/target/test-classes/schema.json#","pointer":"/properties/Data/items/0/properties/Name"}
    instance: {"pointer":"/Data/0/Name"}
    domain: "validation"
    keyword: "type"
    found: "object"
    expected: ["string"]

  Actual: {
  "Data": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": {
        "FirstName": "First",
        "LastName": "Last"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Maven project (`pom.xml`)

```
<properties>
    <restassured.version>5.1.1</restassured.version>
</properties>
```

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>${restassured.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${restassured.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
        <artifactId>wiremock-jre8</artifactId>
        <version>2.33.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

#### JSON schema (`src/test/resources/schema.json`)

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Data": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "Id": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "Name": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "Id",
            "Name"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "Data"
  ]
}
```

#### Test data (`src/test/resources/__files/data.json`)

```json
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "ABC"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Test data (`src/test/resources/__files/data-invalid.json`)

```json
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": {
        "FirstName": "First",
        "LastName": "Last"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Unit test class (`src/test/java/info/brunov/stackoverflow/question72903880/DataServiceTest.java`)

```java
package info.brunov.stackoverflow.question72903880;

import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.builder.RequestSpecBuilder;
import io.restassured.filter.log.LogDetail;
import io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public final class DataServiceTest {
    private final WireMockServer server;
    private final RequestSpecification requestSpecification;

    public DataServiceTest() {
        server = new WireMockServer(
            WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig().dynamicPort()
        );
        server.stubFor(
            WireMock.get("/data")
                .willReturn(
                    WireMock.aResponse().withBodyFile("data.json")
                )
        );
        server.stubFor(
            WireMock.get("/data-invalid")
                .willReturn(
                    WireMock.aResponse().withBodyFile("data-invalid.json")
                )
        );
        server.start();

        final RequestSpecBuilder requestSpecBuilder = new RequestSpecBuilder();
        requestSpecBuilder.setPort(server.port());
        requestSpecification = requestSpecBuilder.build();
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        server.stop();
    }

    @Test
    public void getData_responseConformsSchema_success() {
        RestAssured.given()
            .spec(requestSpecification)
            .get("/data")
            .then()
            .log().ifValidationFails(LogDetail.ALL)
            .assertThat()
            .statusCode(200)
            .body(JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("schema.json"));
    }

    // NOTE: Deliberately failing test.
    @Test
    public void getInvalidData_responseConformSchema_fail() {
        RestAssured.given()
            .spec(requestSpecification)
            .get("/data-invalid")
            .then()
            .log().ifValidationFails(LogDetail.ALL)
            .assertThat()
            .statusCode(200)
            .body(JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("schema.json"));
    }
}
```